# How to connect WSDL file in my application using SOAP service?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, bpel

I am doing a project using Java and BPEL. I successfully created webservices in Java and integrated them using BPEL. All i generated a single output WSDL file. Now, I have to use this output WSDL file in my application using SOAP communication. How can i do that? Is there any help out side for such scenarios? Walkthroughs are really appreciated..

Comment: Explaining architecture of your application is required to provide a concrete answer/walk-through. (Is it implemented using java?)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the architecture of your application (Standard Java, Spring-based, ...) there might or not be a documented procedure to consume a SOAP-based webservice.

On the other hand, you're always free to pick a webservice development framework to handle that. For instance, you could pick either CXF or AXIS2 (I believe these are the two most popular frameworks for Java WebServices). Each of these frameworks provides a tool called "wsdl2java" that helps you generate client-side/server-side/both Java classes. Then, you can easily add those classes and the requireds libraries to your application.

Having used CXF in the past, It even does provide several way to consume a webservice

- Generating the client-side classes
- Using CXF dynamic client factory : basically, you'll retrieve an endpoint proxy from a factory object.

Hope that'll help

Answer (score 0):

I start with [SoapUI](http://soapui.org) (or downloadable from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/4.0/soapUI-x32-4_0_0.exe)), that will let you consume the WSDL and fire off requests against your server.  Typically I'm hitting someone else's  webservice, and trying to figure out what the data looks like before I start wiring my code together, but in your case its just a verification that the services would be/are working.

Then, as @KHY said, you can automatically convert the wsdl into java with a wsdl2java  and start coding (look under the **Related** list on the right panel of this SO screen)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Java application, then the easiest way to consume a service is using JAX-WS. It's really easy to create a Web service client from WSDL.

[See this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-jax/index.html)

Once you deploy the BPEL project on server, then refer the WSDL with http://server:port/application/YourBPELProjectService?WSDL in the consuming application. You will need to write different client code based on the BPEL type - Synchronous, Asynchronous etc.